# let vs var: scopes in for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6, closures

Anyone explain this(behavior differences between var and let in for loop) please?

1. classical interview question(closure):

   ```
   let a = [];
   for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
       a[i] = function() {
         console.log(i,);
       }
   }
   a[0](); // 10
   a[1](); // 10
   ```
2. if we use let:

   ```
   let a = [];
   for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {    // var => let
       a[i] = function() {
       console.log(i);
     }
   }

   a[0](); // 1
   a[1](); // 2
   ```

Yes, i is normal and as expected when using 'let'.
The first thought came to my mind is that let doesnt support closure. But no, it supports. (following tested it on Chrome):

```
function bb() {
  let b = 1;
  return function() {
    console.log(b);
  }
}
bb()();    // 1, means a closure is created
```

Then my second explanation is: when using let in for loop. For EVERY loop, it creates a new i repeatedly. And this is proved in chrome debugger by me.

Question is:

if i is created in each loop in the for-loop. How does it keeps increasing??? Why it doesn't just keep being 0 as we declared if it is created every time?

```
for (let i=0; .......)
```

Comment: @thefourtheye Thanks for your lighting fast editing!!!

Comment: Maybe take another look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/let-keyword-vs-var-keyword?rq=1)

Comment: Note that IE doesn't do `let` properly when used in the parentheses of the `for` (but does get it right if `let` is used in the body of the `for`).

Comment: @Wickramaranga it's a good one with covering most of the aspects. thx!

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for pointing out 'let in IE'. I think it explains something. That means parentheses is somehow different from { ... }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your example, the environment for the "lexical declaration" `let i` is being created every iteration.  However, the `for` loop uses the previous environment in order to create the next environment.  So when the increment occurs it begins where it left off.  Otherwise using `let` to declare `i` would create an infinite loop (i.e. `i` would always be `<10`).

How it works:

In the for loop [body evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-forbodyevaluation), the step after 'test' and 'result' is [CreatePerIterationEnvironment(perIterationBindings)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createperiterationenvironment) which declares a new environment and initializes all the bindings to their last known value: `thisIterationEnv.InitializeBinding(bn, lastValue)`.  Once complete the new environment is set as the current environment and the 'increment' step begins.

Definition:

> InitializeBinding(N,V) Set the value of an already existing but uninitialized binding in an Environment Record. The String value N is the text of the bound name. V is the value for the binding and is a value of any ECMAScript language type.

Answer (score 1):

The first one, the wrong(unexpected) result is just because closures have access to the updated values of the outer function’s variables(finally the variable 'i' in closures is 10);

---

The second one, use `let` to declare variable `i` to mark it as a `block variable` which means the closures get the immediate `i`(like IIFE).